# Filter Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, filter

I have been trying to filter a dictionary to find which statements in the dictionary fit and then print them. The idea is that all statements where the cost of product is greater than money paid is being printed. I do not know how to filter those out. Below is the code being used:

```
data = open("tableQuotes.txt","r")
for line in data:
    line = line.strip()
    (quote, customer, amount, paid) = line.split(",")
    left = int(amount)-int(paid)
    dbase2[quote] = (customer, amount, paid, left)
data.close()
```

What do I add to filter out those specific statements?

Comment: Can you show how exactly the dictionary looks? I.e. (a short excerpt of) what `print(dbase)` shows.

Comment: Consider using any kind dictionary comprehensions with proper `if` condition.

Comment: @tobias_k This is what printing dbase2 looks like: http://pastebin.com/kMnK0nyE

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
dbase2 = {"quote1": ("customer1", 150, 80, 70),
          "quote2": ("customer2", 100, 100, 0),
          "quote3": ("customer3", 200, 50, 150)}

has_left = {quote: data for quote, data in dbase2.items() if data[3] > 0}
```

Or with some more tuple unpacking:

```
has_left = {quote: (c, a, p ,l) for quote, (c, a, p ,l) in dbase2.items() if l > 0}
```

Both ways, `has_left` ends up as `{'quote3': ('customer3', 200, 50, 150), 'quote1': ('customer1', 150, 80, 70)}`